# C++ Qt Finding every disk in /dev/

Tags: c++, macos, qt, usb

I have a C++ code that searches for every directory containing the word 'disk' inside the directory /dev/ (im on a mac) which is where all USB drives are, but when I'm doing `QRegExp("disk*")` it can't find any, but when I do 'mount' in Terminal, i can find my USB named disk1s5. Why can't I find it with QRegExp?

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
DIR *dir = NULL;
dirent *search = NULL;
dir = opendir("/dev/");
if (dir != NULL)
{
    while ((search = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        QRegExp exp("disk*");
        exp.setPatternSyntax(QRegExp::Wildcard);
        exp.setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
        if (exp.exactMatch(search->d_name))
        {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 2;
        }

    }
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

## endif

Comment: Please post your code. How do you use QRegExp?

Comment: I've updated my post with code

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're confusing globbing (wildcards used in shells etc) and regular expressions. But they are not the same.

In regular expressions, `*` means *the preceding item appears zero or more times*. As such, `disk*` matches the strings `dis`, `disk`, `diskk`, `diskkk` and so on.

If you want to check for `disk` followed by anything (including nothing), you must use `disk.*` where `.` means *any character* so `.*` means *any character appearing zero or more times*. This corresponds exactly to the globbing pattern `disk*`.

Depending on your needs, you could also use `disk.+` to match for `disk` followed by *any character appearing **one** or more times* (which, compared to `disk.*`, does not match the string `disk` itself).

I strongly suggest you read the [documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qregexp.html#details) to understand how regular expressions really work.

Comment: Note that `QRegExp` can use wildcard syntax if you pass `QRegExp::Wildcard` to its constructor.

Comment: @Riateche Good point. You should post that as a separate answer in case OP prefers globbing over regular expressions.

Comment: Well, that didnt work, this is my RegExp: `            QRegExp exp("disk*");
            exp.setPatternSyntax(QRegExp::Wildcard);
            exp.setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
            if (exp.exactMatch(search->d_name))
            {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return 2;
            }`

Comment: Okay guys, I found the answer, I'm an idiot, instead of putting exp->exactmatch I had search->exactMatch . Thanks anyway and I apologize for my dumb mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find all `disk*` dirs from `/dev` and you are using Qt, you can do it like this:

```
QDir dir("/dev");
QStringList nameFilter = QStringList() << "disk*";
QStringList disks = dir.entryList(nameFilter, QDir::System|QDir::Dirs);

foreach (QString d, disks)
    qDebug() << d;
```